# My UILabel is not displaying when my if statement is false

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, uilabel

I have a story board that has a `UITextField`, `UIButton`, `UIImage`, and `UILabel` to display the images in an array. If you type the correct name for the image file into a text field. So, the problem is that once the text field input does *not* match, it should update the `UILabel` to display `"Result not found"`, but it doesn't.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    myClass *myNewClass;
    NSMutableArray *picArray;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    picArray = [@[@"Button_Red",@"Button_Green"]mutableCopy];  
}

- (IBAction)displayImageAction:(id)sender
{ 
    NSString *titleSearched = self.textSearchField.text;
    NSString *titleNotHere = self.notFoundLabel.text;

    //Declare a bool variable here and set
    BOOL variable1;

    for (int i = 0; i < picArray.count; i++)
    {
        NSString *currentPic = picArray[i];

        if ([titleSearched isEqualToString:currentPic])
        {
            variable1 = YES;
        }
    }


    if (variable1 == YES) {
        //this works fine displays the image
        self.outputImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed: titleSearched];
        [self.textSearchField resignFirstResponder];
    } else {
        //problem is here its not showing when input for the array is not equal it should display a message label "Result Not Found" but it remains blank on the IOS simulator

        titleNotHere = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Result Not found"];
        [self.textSearchField resignFirstResponder];
    }
}

//Get rid of the texfield when done typing
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // Retract keyboard if up
    [self.textSearchField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: And what is `titleNotHere`? Is it set to something or nil?

Comment: NSString *titleNotHere = self.notFoundLabel.text; is set to this hope this helps

Comment: variable1 should be set at FALSE at its declaration line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that

`titleNotHere = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Result Not found"];`

simply sets the method variable `titleNotHere`.

What you want is

`self.notFoundLabel.text=@"Result Not found";`

You will also want

`self.notFoundLabel.text=@"";`

when the result is found.

Comment: its not displaying the text UILabel it just leaves it blank.

Comment: Have you bound the UILabel to your notFoundLabel property in IB?  Have you stepped through your code in the debugger to see if anything is nil?

Comment: No I have not and yes it returns nil so do i just connect the UIlabel to the IBaction

Comment: You need to drag from the UILabel to the "files owner" or view controller object (if you are using Storyboards) and connect to to the IBOutlet for your property

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
NSString *titleNotHere = self.notFoundLabel.text;
```

stores the text from the label into a variable, but updating that variable again will not change the label text - it only changes what that variable points to.

You need to explicitly update the label text:

```
self.notFoundLabel.text = @"Result Not found";
```

note also that this uses a string literal - you don't need to use a format string as you aren't adding any parameters to it.

Also, when checking booleans, don't use `if (variable1 == YES) {`, just use `if (variable1) {` (it's safer).

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to SET the value to the variable

`self.notFoundLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Result Not found"]`

or

`self.notFoundLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Result Not found"]`

`UILabel.text = @"whatever..."` is actually converted into `[UILable setText:@"whatever..."]`.

`NSString *labelText = UILabel.text` has to be thought as `NSString *labelText = [UILabel text]`;